# Get LatLng coordinates from SIRGAS2000 UTM 21s coords

Tags: google-maps-api, utm, latitude-longitude

I have a bunch of locations (36k) and they are represented using SIRGAS2000 (UTM 21s) coordinates. I need some way of converting them to traditional LatLng format so I can upload them to my database and use those coords with Google Maps API.

I could use either a formula to translate them to LatLng before uploading, or some kind of API to convert them before using them in my app (after uploading them as they are to my database).

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

You can import your locations into QGIS/ArcMap/MapInfo or a spatialite/postgis database using the SIRGAS2000 (UTM 21s) coordinates. Then reproject the data to WGS84 and export the coordinates and location ids into a format that your database will import such as csv.

Comment: QGIS is free and should handle it